# Reading Virtual Serial Port with MicroC for 8051

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I have a problem , please help me.
for about a project homework ı need read from virtual serial port with microC and send this info to AT89C52 microconttoller..
This is my source code:

```
int uart_rd;
void main() {

    P1=0X00;
    UART1_Init(9600);
    delay_ms(100);

    while(1)
    {    
      if(UART1_Data_Ready()){

         uart_rd=UART1_read();

         if(uart_rd=='1')
         {P1=0X01; delay_ms(1500); P1=0X00; }

         if(uart_rd=='2')
         {P1=0X02; delay_ms(1500); P1=0X00; }
      }
   }
}
```

BUT I cant get info from the port. Where is the mistake.Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your UART receive variable (`uart_rd`) as an `int`, which is a 2 byte variable.  I would expect `UART1_read()` to return a single byte (`char`).

I am not familiar with your particular setup or debugging/troubleshooting options, but you might try writing some code to assist in debugging your issue.  The following example *may* be useful.  It does assume that LEDs are connected to both port 1 and port 2, so some adjustment may be necessary.

```
char uart_rd;

void main() 
{
    UART1_Init(9600);  // Initialize UART at 9600 bps
    delay_ms(100);     // Wait for UART to stabilize

    while(1)
    {    
        if(UART1_Data_Ready())
        {
            P2 = 0xFF;               // Turn ON PORT2 LEDs upon data ready
            uart_rd = UART1_read();  // Receive data
            P1 = uart_rd;            // Display data on port 1 LEDs
            UART1_write(uart_rd);    // Transmit same data back
            delay_ms(1500);          // Brief delay
            P1 = 0x00;               // Turn OFF port 1 LEDs
            P2 = 0x00;               // Turn OFF port 2 LEDs
        }
    }
}
```